# How to handle org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have Kafka client with this configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092
          zkNodes: localhost:2181
          configuration:
            security:
              protocol: SASL_SSL
            sasl:
              mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-256
              kerberos:
                 service:
                    name: "kafka"
              jaas:
                config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="user" password="sepultura1";
              
      bindings:
        kafkaDemoTopic:
          destination: kafka_demo_topic
```

When I tried to run application, It fails on this exception:

```
org.springframework.cloud.stream.provisioning.ProvisioningException: Provisioning exception encountered for kafka_demo_topic
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:377) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:197) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:96) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:297) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:102) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:153) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.doBindProducer(BindingService.java:353) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:294) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.resolveDestination(StreamBridge.java:272) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.send(StreamBridge.java:168) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.send(StreamBridge.java:147) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.send(StreamBridge.java:142) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.heller.kafka.demo.producer.KafkaProducer.scheduleFixedRateTask(KafkaProducer.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.runInternal(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:130) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.lambda$run$2(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:124) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:499) ~[micrometer-observation-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:124) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:396) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2096) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:180) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicAndPartitions(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:413) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicIfNecessary(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:387) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:364) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:316) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1277) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1209) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.runDelegatedTasks(SslTransportLayer.java:435) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeUnwrap(SslTransportLayer.java:523) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:373) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshake(SslTransportLayer.java:293) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:178) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:543) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:571) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.processRequests(KafkaAdminClient.java:1381) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1312) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:285) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1335) ~[na:na]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:127) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[na:na]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

I have imported certificates into cacerts key store. Can someone give me a point how to deal with this exception? It seems that certificates in cacerts store is invalid. I cant find on the google how to handle it. Thank you

I run this commands to generate + self signed certificates:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -keyout ca.key -out ca.crt -subj "/C=PL/L=Warsaw/CN=localhost" -passout pass:sepultura1

keytool -genkey -keystore server.keystore -alias localhost -dname CN=localhost -keyalg RSA -validity 365 -ext san=dns:localhost -storepass sepultura1

 keytool -certreq -keystore server.keystore -alias localhost -file server.unsigned.crt -storepass sepultura1

openssl x509 -req -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -in server.unsigned.crt -out server.crt -days 365 -CAcreateserial -passin pass:sepultura1


keytool -import -file ca.crt -keystore server.keystore -alias ca -storepass sepultura1 -noprompt

keytool -import -file server.crt -keystore server.keystore -alias localhost -storepass sepultura1 -noprompt

keytool -import -file ca.crt -keystore client.truststore -alias ca -storepass sepultura1 -noprompt

keytool -import -file server.crt -keystore client.truststore -alias localhost -storepass sepultura1 -noprompt

keytool -import -file server.crt -keystore C:\apps\jdk17\lib\security\cacerts -alias localhost -storepass changeit -noprompt

keytool -import -file ca.crt -keystore C:\apps\jdk17\lib\security\cacerts -alias ca -storepass changeit -noprompt
```

but still get this exception:

```
org.springframework.cloud.stream.provisioning.ProvisioningException: Provisioning exception encountered for kafka_demo_topic
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:377) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:197) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:96) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:297) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:102) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:153) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.doBindProducer(BindingService.java:353) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:294) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.resolveDestination(StreamBridge.java:272) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.send(StreamBridge.java:168) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.send(StreamBridge.java:147) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.send(StreamBridge.java:142) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.heller.kafka.demo.producer.KafkaProducer.scheduleFixedRateTask(KafkaProducer.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.runInternal(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:130) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.lambda$run$2(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:124) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:499) ~[micrometer-observation-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:124) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:396) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2096) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:180) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicAndPartitions(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:413) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicIfNecessary(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:387) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:364) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:316) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1277) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1209) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.runDelegatedTasks(SslTransportLayer.java:435) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeUnwrap(SslTransportLayer.java:523) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:373) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshake(SslTransportLayer.java:293) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:178) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:543) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:571) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.processRequests(KafkaAdminClient.java:1381) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1312) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:285) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1335) ~[na:na]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:127) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[na:na]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Comment: The error you got from `openssl s_client ... -tls1` does not mean anything is wrong with your certificate; the TLS 1.0 protocol is obsolete, broken, and widely prohibited for a decade now, so no decent server should accept it, and recent OpenSSL like yours won't even send it. Note however that once you let `s_client` use a reasonable protocol, it does NOT fail (even) if the certificate is bad, so that is not a sufficient check; you need to actually look _at_ the certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create certificates this way:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -keyout C:\apps\certs\ca-key -out C:\apps\certs\ca-cert  -days 999
  
keytool -keystore C:\apps\certs\kafka.truststore.jks  -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert

keytool -keystore kafka.keystore.jks -alias localhost -validity 9999 -genkey -keyalg RSA

keytool -keystore kafka.keystore.jks -alias localhost -certreq -file cert-file

openssl x509 -req -CA ca-cert -CAkey ca-key -in cert-file -out cert-signed  -days 9999 -CAcreateserial

keytool -keystore kafka.keystore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert

keytool -keystore kafka.keystore.jks -alias localhost -import -file cert-signed

keytool -keystore kafka.truststore.jks  -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert

keytool -keystore C:\apps\jdk17\lib\security\cacerts -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert

keytool -keystore C:\apps\jdk17\lib\security\cacerts -alias localhost -import -file cert-signed
```

2. check if project in Eclipse point to correct jvm. I have bad path with Eclipse default jvm. When I point to right location, it runs.

Comment: Good catch. Upvoted. So you are setting up SSL/TLS for Kafka by creating a self-signed Certificate Authority (CA), generating a keystore for Kafka, and importing the necessary certificates into the appropriate truststores.

Answer (score 1):

> I have imported certificates into cacerts key store.

So I will assume the Java Runtime Environment's (JRE) default truststore, which is typically located at `<JAVA_HOME>/lib/security/cacerts`.

By "certificates", I will also assume the certificates of the [trusted CAs -- certificate authority --](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/content/kafka-demo-securing-communication-between-clients-and-brokers.html#__a_id_step_2_a_create_certificate_authority_ca) validating the certificate used by your Kafka broker. Because if those certificates are not CAs, that can only mean your broker uses a self-signed certificate.

If you are using the default Java cacerts keystore, and it is located in its standard location (`<JAVA_HOME>/lib/security/cacerts`), you would not typically need to use the [Kafka Binder Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/kafka/kafka-binder/config-options.html) `certificateStoreDirectory` property. The Kafka Binder should use the default truststore as it is.

Check first if your Spring Boot project does not already include an SSL configuration in your Kafka client.
It could overwrite the default `cacerts` (where you imported your certificates, CAs or self-signed).

Within your Spring Boot project, look for `application.yml` or `application.properties`. That file is usually found in the `src/main/resources` directory. If you have environment-specific configuration files, they may be named like `application-dev.yml`, `application-prod.yml`, etc. Depending on whether you are using YAML (`application.yml`) or properties format (`application.properties`), the configuration will differ slightly.

For `application.yml`, the Kafka SSL configuration would look like this:

```yaml
spring:
   kafka:
      producer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      ssl:
         truststore:
            location: /path/to/your/truststore.jks
            password: truststorepassword
            alias: my-kafka-broker
```

For `application.properties`, it would be:

```
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/your/truststore.jks
spring.kafka.producer.ssl.truststore.password=truststorepassword
spring.kafka.producer.ssl.truststore.alias=my-kafka-broker
# or
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.certificateStoreDirectory=/path/to/your/truststore.jks
```

But If you do not have any SSL settings in your configuration, then you can check the `cacerts` keystore:

`keytool -list -v -keystore <JAVA_HOME>/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit`

Look for an alias or a subject that matches your Kafka broker's identity. The subject typically contains a CN (Common Name) that might be the hostname of the broker.

The first step is to check your `cacerts` does [include a CA Certificate](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/content/kafka-demo-securing-communication-between-clients-and-brokers.html#__a_id_step_7_a_import_ca_certificate_to_client_truststore), which was used to [sign your broker certificate](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/content/kafka-demo-securing-communication-between-clients-and-brokers.html#__a_id_step_4_a_sign_broker_certificate_using_ca).

Check also the certificate used by your Kafka broker, with:

```bash
# Save the certificate
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect kafka-broker-host:kafka-broker-port -showcerts | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > kafka-broker-cert.pem

# Check if the certificate is self-signed
openssl verify -CAfile kafka-broker-cert.pem kafka-broker-cert.pem
```

If the certificate is self-signed, `openssl verify` will return a result like `kafka-broker-cert.pem: OK`.
That means the certificate itself should be imported into the `cacerts` truststore.

Comment: I try to add certs into application.yml, but without success.

Comment: That `openssl verify` willl succeed even if the leaf cert isn't self-signed as long as it is signed by/under a root _that is sent by the server_ -- I don't know if kafka does so (according to TLS RFCs it's optional).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 OK. The main issue remains, as you noticed, the TLS1.0 usage. That would not work indeed.